# How to configure DirectLineSpeech for Dialogs?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, direct-line-botframework

How do I configure the "Speak()" for saying out the prompts and other waterfall messages like the [DirectLine Speech Echo bot sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/directline-speech/csharp_dotnetcore/02.echo-bot) for DirectLineSpeech does?

I tried using the [DirectLine Speech Core-bot sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/directline-speech/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot), but it just "speaks" the welcome and final message as those leverage the `SpeakExtensions.Speak()` as shown in the `FinalStepAsync() method` in [this file](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/experimental/directline-speech/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs).

Answer (score 0):

When using Prompts and Waterfall messages, you are directly using the SDK methods which send the message. As a consequence, you cannot add the `Speak` field to your message easily.

It may evolve in the future as DirectLine Speech is still experimental in the samples, but I don't think that you could do something in a few lines of code today.

One idea could be the implementation of a Middleware (see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-activity-processing?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365&view=azure-bot-service-4.0#middleware) for the concept of Middleware in Bot Framework) which would modify the `Speak` field for every outgoing Activity, given the Activity type (`ActivityTypes.Message` in your case) and content.

You can get inspiration for the Translate Middleware in the samples, see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/17.multilingual-bot/Translation/TranslationMiddleware.cs)

Comment: Thanks, trying out this approach. I assumed the sample would have that incorporated - raised a bug on them to see if this is unintentional - https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/1870#issuecomment-548034886